# ModelMultipleChoiceField field returning no value

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, django-admin-filters

```
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = Document
    starred_by = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        widgets = {

            'created_by': AutocompleteSelect(
                Document._meta.get_field('created_by').remote_field,
                admin.site,
                attrs={'data-dropdown-auto-width': 'true'}
            ),
            'organisation': AutocompleteSelect(
                Document._meta.get_field('created_by').remote_field,
                admin.site,
                attrs={'data-dropdown-auto-width': 'true'}
            ),
            'starred_by':AutocompleteSelectMultiple(
                Document._meta.get_field('starred_by').remote_field,
                admin.site,
                attrs={'data-dropdown-auto-width': 'true'}
            )
        }
```

***Update:***

I have read a bit about the [select2](https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library but I am having trouble understanding how do I integrate it with Django-admin my requirements mostly are ***searchable select dropdown for foreign keys and multi-select dropdowns for many-to-many fields*** but these fields I want in the Django admin panel in my apps, any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it , I used Django's native search fields which uses Sleect2 under the hood

```
class OrganisationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ('name','address')
        autocomplete_fields  = ['products']
        search_fields = ['name__iexact']
        # autocomplete_fields = ['']
    
    
    class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        search_fields = ['name']
```